# Firebase TypeError when trying to initialize

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using firebase (the old API), and cant even get the initialization to work. I installed firebase with npm install firebase --save, and all I have in my file is:

```
var Firebase = require("firebase");

var firebaseRef = new Firebase("https://my-app.firebaseio.com");
```

And when I run node that-file.js I get:

```
var firebaseRef = new Firebase("https://my-app.firebaseio.com");
                  ^
TypeError: object is not a function
```

Did something break when they moved over to the new console? Can i not use the old firebase api anymore?

Comment: The code would be correct for client(browser) but it's different for server side. See *npm firebase* https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase

Comment: check for the version of the firebase. I had faced a lot of problems with versions.

Comment: It was indeed due to npm install firebase installing the new firebase version managed by google. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're likely on the new version of Firebase. Install the specific version before the `3.0` release.

```
npm install firebase@2.4.2 --save
```